# Delete an SSL certificate for ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, ssl

I added an SSL certificate to ArcGIS Server, and named it `*.mydomain.net`.

ArcGIS Server does not seem to like the asterisk though; when trying to open the REST interface (https://ags.mydomain.net/arcgis/admin/machines/AGS.MYDOMAIN.NET/sslcertificates/*.mydomain.net) the browser just shows *Bad Request* (Firefox) or *Cannot find webpage* (IE). Replacing `*` with `%2A` does not work either.

Obviously, I cannot delete this certificate through the web interface now.

Is there a way to do this manually? Maybe there's a directory, or registry enter or whatever where AGS stores certificates?

(Note: I already added the same certificate with a valid name too, and everything works, it's just that I want to clean up the mess)

Comment: * can't be valid char in file. Check what's name of .cer file in folder C:\arcgisserver\config-store\machines\AGS.MYDOMAIN.NET

Comment: That folder only has a file called SelfsignedCertificate.cer and arcgis.keystore

Comment: I have the same stuff there. I was able to generate certificate *.mydomain.net, ArcGIS updated file arcgis.keystore. But I was able to navigate to URL .../sslcertificates/*.mydomain.net/delete and delete the certificate. I am using ArcGIS 10.3. Maybe there are issues with such URLs on 10.4.

Comment: This is 10.2.2. The __*__ prevents me from opening that link. I added /delete to the URL, but still no fun.

Comment: You can use Java's keytool, like: "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore arcgis.keystore to list certificates and then remove it. But I don't know what password ArcGIS uses for keystore.

Answer (score 1):

C:\ArcGIS\Server\framework\etc\certificates contains a file called keystorepass.dat  open it in notepad and it contains the password for the keystore.

Comment: with ArcGIS Server v10.61 the contents of the `keystorepass.dat` file is `{crypt}...long_hash_string...` which wasn't much use. I did however find the password in `Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml` by searching for `keystorePass`